# ¿Por qué hay textos en español que cambian a inglés y después a español?

Tags: bug, estado-completado, traducciones

La pantalla para iniciar una recompensa hace unas horas estaba en inglés:

> [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y ahora aparece en español. También pasó con otras cadenas como "Hot meta posts". Por qué pasa esto?

Comment: Acabamos de enterarnos de un bug que esta mandando información incorrecta a las paginas renderizadas. Anteriormente fueron las descripciones de las medallas las cuales corregimos ya.  Voy a investigar esto también para que nos devuelvan nuestras traducciones. Estoy al pendiente de esto.

Comment: Lo que menciona fedorqui no es menor: si tan sólo fuese un problema al renderizar las páginas, aparecería la traducción original en Transifex, y no se vería en el sitio... **Pero** no están traducidas en Transifex ([ejemplo](https://www.transifex.com/stack-exchange/stack-overflow-es/translate/#es/$/133316105?key=6cb55cf7ae366f6d01dc0f9eaaef30cd))... Entonces, una de dos: o nunca estuvieron en Transifex, estaban hardcoddeadas y decidieron aplicar la l10n en todas las páginas recién ahora (y por eso tanta movida y tanto sin traducir); o están haciendo algo raro que eliminó la antigua traducción

Comment: Retuerzo la pregunta un poco para explicar qué está pasando ([con el consentimiento de fedorqui](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/42717053#42717053))

Comment: @Mariano agregando más contexto: son páginas que no han sido modificadas en mucho tiempo (no sé esta en particular, pero en otra instancia de esto, en el perfil, la cadena destraducida no había sido modificada en 4 años).

Comment: Comentaba esto a @g3rv4, pensé podría ser mi imaginación! :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Actualización:** [el bug fue corregido](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/307136/238921)

Cada vez que hacemos un build de Q&A (aproximadamente 20 veces por día) se extraen las traducciones de transifex y se las inserta en la dll con el sitio. Después se copian las dlls a los distintos servidores web.

En este proceso hay un bug que hace que, "a veces" "algunas" cadenas no sean correctamente importadas.

Entonces, lo que se ve es que algunas cadenas aparecen en inglés hasta que se hace otro build (y entonces, "otras" cadenas aparecen en inglés).

Esto es un bug del que estamos al tanto, los desarrolladores que trabajan en la localización están al tanto, y va a ser corregido. Lamentablemente no tenemos un ETA.

El uso de comillas es únicamente porque no hemos encontrado un patrón, y además cuando se corrigen algunas cadenas a veces se destraducen otras.

Comment: como que no hay ETA?? no es 8?

Comment: @gbianchi se refiere a tiempo estimado para corregirlo.

Comment: Siempre al pié del cañón @g3rv4! Qué bueno que se terminaron las de̒ͭ͌̈̍s͐ͧ̂tͧ̈ͧͤ̋r̐aͨͧd͑ͬ̓uͧͪͣ̃̍͐c̽̑͋͂ͤiͮ̐͗̆̆̑̓d͗̍̌ͧa̍ͯͧs̎͊̄̌̌ͨ́

Comment: @Mariano mi granito de arena fue asegurarme que pudieran reproducirlo... no es mucho, pero es mío ;)

Comment: Ah, no sabía eso!!! ¿Y lo decís humildemente?!!! Puede ser lo más complicado con estas cosas!! Groso