# No hay traducción para la antigüedad de las preguntas

Tags: bug, estado-completado, traducciones

No hay traducción para el texto de la antigüedad de las preguntas, por [ejemplo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/42393), dice:

> formulada 1 years, 1 months ago

Debería decir:

> formulada hace 1 año(s), 1 mes(es)

---

> [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿A qué te refieres exactamente? ¿Podrías darnos un poco más de contexto? ¿Existe algo que esté haciendo falta?

Comment: @Flxtr sí, "el edad" de las preguntas sin la traduccíon.

Comment: Comprendo @edem. Actualmente hay 3 hilos que tratan acerca de traducciones y algunos problemas que se han presentado últimamente, [este](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/40/qu%C3%A9-textos-hay-que-no-han-sido-traducidos), [este](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/3133/qu%C3%A9-hacemos-con-los-hilos-de-lista-de-cosas-sobre-traducciones) y [este](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/3133/qu%C3%A9-hacemos-con-los-hilos-de-lista-de-cosas-sobre-traducciones). Lo ideal sería seguir retroalimentando esas preguntas a modo de concentrar la informaión en un solo lugar ;)

Comment: @edem realmente, creo que convendría que sigas el consejo que te dieron, eliminando de acá y publicando en https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/40/qu%C3%A9-textos-hay-que-no-han-sido-traducidos

Answer (score 1):

Esta es una de las cadenas que perdió su traducción al arreglar "[el bug](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/3129/11272)" (ya que el órden de los parámetros en el variant cambió).

Ya aprobé la traducción e hice pull. En el próximo build queda traducido.

Answer (score 0):

Juan M actualizó hace unas cuantas horas [su respuesta](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/515/65) a [¿Qué textos hay que no han sido traducidos?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/40/65).

En este caso la cadena reportada si está en Transifex pero no contaba con traducción, pero ya la traduje así como las variantes de la misma.