# Warning: Vamos a sincronizar las cadenas de SOes con Transifex

Tags: discusión, estado-completado, traducciones

Después de "[la charla](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3093/11272)" algunos seguimos frecuentando la [sala de chat de traducciones](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/72224/hablemos-sobre-las-traducciones) para seguir conversando sobre el proceso, cadenas que faltan... en fin, para coordinar el trabajo de traducción (que va a ser una constante en el sitio).

Entre todo esto, [tuvimos un bug](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3127/11272) que "quedó arreglado" y ahora parece que tenemos otro. El problema con estos bugs es que deshacen el trabajo de los traductores y revisores... haciendo que la comunidad invierta horas en traducir que a veces sirve y otras veces no.

Para esto, estamos pensando en tener un sistema independiente a Stack Overflow que nos permita manejar las traducciones a nosotros... de esa forma, nuevos bugs no harían que perdamos el trabajo. ¿Cómo va a funcionar esto? No tenemos mucha idea... pero tampoco es el objetivo de este post.

En el estado actual, hay muchas cadenas traducidas en la base de datos de SOes que no están traducidas en Transifex, y eso complica sabér qué falta y qué no. Nosotros podemos hacer un "push a Transifex", pero probablemente perdamos traducciones no aprobadas.

Una vez que hagamos el push, una forma de continuar (mientras el bug siga en la vuelta) es coordinar las traducciones en el chat... si hay una cadena para traducir (y es visible en el sitio... no nos importan las cadenas que no están), hacemos traducción -> aprobación -> pull de transifex para asegurarnos de no perderla.

No quería hacer el "push a Transifex" sin avisar por acá, para que quienes están en el tema pero no en el chat, no se vean sorprendidos por traducciones perdidas. Por otro lado, en la situación actual lo mejor sería **no entrar a transifex a ver qué falta traducir**... sino sólo traducir cadenas que estén en inglés en el sitio y coordinar los esfuerzos en el chat.

**Update:** Hoy sincronizamos las cadenas de la base de datos con Transifex... y nos encontramos con la grata sorpresa de que hay muchas menos sin traducir de lo que pensamos! pasamos a 1400 sin traducir y 119 sin revisar.

Probablemente hagamos el mismo proceso de vuelta en el futuro, por lo que el proceso de traducir por ahora sigue muy centralizado en el chat.

Comment: Gracias por el "Warning" y las atenciones para quienes participan en las traducciones. Es muy bueno saber que tendrás el respaldo y todo lo demás que nos compartes. Dale sin miedo :)

Comment: Ya deseo ver esos cambios @g3rv4, a veces, "mi no entender el "espanglish"" saludos!!!